# When i know the value "c", How do I find factored numbers "a" and "b" : (a*b) == c (mod N) where, N is bitcoin order

Tags: rsa, cryptocurrency

When i know the value "c", How do I find factored numbers "a" and "b" : (a*b) == c (mod N) where, N is bitcoin order.

For example,
0x2eb4110dd5ca04a63de5b4ba2654ad2012ece01827e92af6734553150fae332a * 0x251469c4e7202526c1571ba2e9a9d90ad46f52172b9d63e779a2165ee7201f66 == 0x5a1b9916812f186ef2c26f314fccd20af8222b022b0154e62c9e3f9c30310145 (mod N)

then i want to know the value, 0x2eb4~ and 0x2514~. Does any method exist?

Comment: It's unclear what "factored numbers" are, and the constraints on $a$ and $b$. What about for example $a=1$ and $b=c$? Or any $a\in[1,c)$ and $b=a^{-1}c\bmod N$? Note: the order of [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1) is $N=$0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141 (just below $2^{256}$), and that matches the example given.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear questions. This example means the latter(not means a=1 and b=c). N is 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141. If I could derive the values of a and b from c....  It is assumed that it( c ) can be decomposed

Comment: What do you expect to do with the factors? Do you really think you can break ECDSA by factoring some number like RSA as you've tagged this question as such? I don't know if I should feel amused or pity for you.

Comment: If the question asks how to find some $a$ and $b$ of known factorization and near 256-bit such that $a\,b\equiv c\pmod N$, that's easy, since most 256-bit integers are easy to factor: pick a random $a\in[1,N)$, compute $b=a^{-1}c\bmod N$ (that's `b=pow(a,-1,N)*c%N` in python), and factor $a$ and $b$ (or try another $a$ in the unlikely case that turns out to be hard). But I don't see the point.

Comment: Because $N$ is prime, any integer $a$ such that $0 < a < N$ has a corresponding value $b$ such that $ab \equiv c \pmod{N}$.  You can literally just choose one.  There is no way to know what $a$ and $b$ values were used by someone to compute $c$ because any nonzero choice of $a$ could have been used.  As a simple example, you could choose $a=1$ in which case $b=c$.  fgrieu's comment shows how to compute $b$ given $a$.